# Does Pentecostalism teach that everyone should pray in tongues?

Tags: pentecostalism, speaking-in-tongues

1. Do Pentecostals teach that only people who speak in tongues are baptized with the Holy Spirit?
2. Do Pentecostals teach that we should all strive to pray in tongues?

Or is this something that Pentecostalism is divided about?

Answer (score 3):

The Foursquare denomination had updated their position years back, around the time Jack Hayford was it’s President, that it was no longer considered a necessary component of being considered Spirit-filled. It was still encouraged and valued, but was considered a gift among others, and not the only evidence. I am having trouble finding if that remains their official position, however.

This isn’t official, but hopefully helpful:
Jack Hayford wrote in his 1992 book *The beauty of spiritual language: a journey toward the heart of God* (Word Pub., Dallas):

> “one must not establish a law of tongues as necessary to spirit baptism”.

(from [Chapter 6](https://archive.org/details/beautyofspiritua0000hayf_f6w4/page/88/mode/1up), pg. 89-107)

Comment: Thank you, that is a helpful answer! I looked up the numbers, and it turns out that Foursquare is one of the largest Pentacostal Denominations. I also saw that the Assemblies of God are much larger still. Knowing their view also would be useful.

Comment: Rieman, I’m delighted this was useful to you. It appears the AoG still holds that speaking in tongues is absolutely required to be considered Spirit-filled. 

https://news.ag.org/en/Features/FAQ-Speaking-in-Tongues